# Nativescript Default child route

Tags: angular, nativescript

How can I navigate to /account/dashboard, when the the router is '/account' ?
Here are my routes, which are currently not working.
The component that is being loaded is AccountPage, rather than AccountDashboardPage ?

```
export const routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", component: HomePage },
    { path: "settings", component: SettingsPage },
    { path: "checkout", component: CheckoutPage },
    { path: "login", component: LoginPage },
    { path: "categories", component: CategoriesPage },
    { path: "category/subcategories/:id", component: SubcategoryList, pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "category/:id", component: CategoryProducts, pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "product/:id", component: ProductPage },
    {
        path: 'account',
        component: AccountPage, 
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [
            { path: "", redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: AccountDashboardPage}
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your template of your `AccountPage` component ?

Comment: There is not template, its an empty string. I have only put a console.log in the constructor.

Comment: Did you read this https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-nested-router-outlets-with-nativescript-and-angular ?

Comment: No I havent, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed

```
component: AccountPage,
```

it all worked out!